# Error nodejs connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, node.js, host

Nodejs trying to connect to a database and pulls me hostinger this error before i use http://www.freemysqlhosting.net/ was similarly placing the host, user, pass and name of the database and did not erro I think that is the port but idk .. I'm using: `app.listen (process.env.PORT || 3000)`

So I'm doing:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection ({
  host: 'mysql.hostinger.es',
  user: 'XXXXX',
  password: 'XX',
  database: 'XXX',
});
```

Error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that it couldn't resolve `mysql.hostinger.es`

Check it's the good hostname or try to set directly the IP address.